# How do I assign variables within WMI calls?

Tags: python, wmi

Using WMI within Python to request data from other servers. I know my credentials are correct, as I can hard-code them in the file and connect without issues. However, my string formatting for variables doesn't seem to be working.

I've tried both of these with no luck:

```
wmi_sql = wmi.WMI(SQLServer_raw, user="%s\\%s", password="%s") % (sql_domain, sql_user, sql_pass)
```

and

```
wmi_sql = wmi.WMI(SQLServer_raw, user="{0}\\{1}", password="{2}").format(sql_domain, sql_user, sql_pass)
```

Tried moving the format() call inside, but it didn't work either:

```
wmi_sql = wmi.WMI(SQLServer_raw, user="{0}\\{1}", password="{2}".format(sql_domain, sql_user, sql_pass))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the string formatters in the wrong place. They need to be used for each string, not the result of the call. As written, python thinks you want to call wmi.WMI and then apply the formatting to whatever is returned.

Try:

```
wmi_sql = wmi.WMI(SQLServer_raw, user="%s\\%s" % (sql_domain, sql_user), 
    password=sql_pass)
```

Answer (score 0):

In one and two you are executing wmi.WMI() and then doing the formatting on the return type. In the third example you are formatting the value of the password but providing three parameters to it hoping it would build user variable. If you really want to build user and password dynamically do this:

```
usr ="{0}\\{1}".format(sql_domain,ql_user)
wmi.WMI(SQLServer_raw, user=usr, password=sql_pass)
```